# React does not re-render when updating state of Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

My table does not rerender, even if the state update does in fact changed the array, but the rerender on the table does not happened.

My initial state is done as below:

```js
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<Pendaftar[]>([]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setData(dataPendaftar);
  }, []);
```

And here is my implementation of the interface:

```
export interface Pendaftar {
  nim: string;
  name: string;
  divisi: string;
  lulus: boolean;
}
```

My handler is done as below:

```js
  const onSelectChange = (nim: string, i: number) => (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>,
  ) => {
    console.log(nim, i, e.target.value);
    const newData = [...data];
    newData[i] = { ...newData[i], lulus: e.target.value === 'true' };
    setData([...newData]);
  };
```

What I'm trying to do here is to re-render the table body when `onSelectChange` is fired.
My table (using Chakra UI):

```js
  return (
    <>
      <Table variant="simple">
        <Thead>
          <Tr>
            <Th>nama</Th>
            <Th>divisi</Th>
            <Th>lulus seleksi form?</Th>
          </Tr>
        </Thead>
        <Tbody>
          {dataPendaftar.map((d, i) => (
            <Tr key={d.nim}>
              <Td>
                {d.name} ({d.nim}) ({d.lulus ? 'y' : 'g'})
              </Td>
              <Td>{d.divisi}</Td>
              <Td>
                <Select
                  defaultValue={'option1'}
                  onChange={onSelectChange(d.nim, i)}
                >
                  <option value="option1" disabled>
                    Pilih
                  </option>
                  <option value="true">Ya</option>
                  <option value="false">Tidak</option>
                </Select>
              </Td>
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
```

I did the logging on the console and the array of objects is changed as it to be, but the re-rendering on the side of table (`({d.lulus ? 'y' : 'g'})`) does not happen. Is there any mishandled on the updating state situation? Any kind of explanation regarding the matter would be helpful for me.

EDIT 1: Tried all the solutions posted and still doesn't work.

Comment: why are you doing `dataPendaftar.map((d, i)` and not on your data state ?

Comment: @Itsky Did you try the solution?

Comment: all answers listed here still doesn't work unfortunately. no idea what's really happening.

Answer (score 2):

replace `onChange={onSelectChange(d.nim, i)` with `onChange={() => onSelectChange(d.nim, i)`

Now you are calling the function once every render, not when the value actually changes

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
const onSelectChange = (nim: string, i: number) => (
  e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
) => {
  setData(data => data.map((item, index)=> {
    if(index === i){
      return {
        ...item,
        lulus: e.target.value === "true",
      };
    }
    return item;
  }));
};
```

```
<Select defaultValue={"option1"} onChange={e => onSelectChange(d.nim, i)}>
  <option value="option1" disabled>
    Pilih
  </option>
  <option value="true">Ya</option>
  <option value="false">Tidak</option>
</Select>;
```